# Key bindings in metacity/gnome WM

Tags: 14.04, gnome, metacity, shortcut-keys

I like to use F6 to toggle raise-or-lower on a window.

I used to be able to set this in: `System Tools -> Preferences -> Keyboard`, but now this needs to be set using `dconf-editor`. Specifically in `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.raise-or-lower`.

Unfortunately setting this value to `F6` doesn't appear to work. Confusingly, setting it to `<Alt>F6` makes it work fine, albeit requiring the use of the Alt key as well.

I don't believe F6 is bound to anything else:

```
> gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | grep F6
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise-or-lower ['F6']
```

What's going on? How can I bind F6 to raise-or-lower in Ubuntu 14.04?